# Give me a link to my removed post in my reputation changes

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, reputation-history, deleted-posts

Since [a user doesn't need 10k reputation in order to view his own deleted question and answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted/108078#108078), It would be nice to have a link to the removed question or answer in reputation changes (when reputation is lost or gained due to the deleted post).

I mean

[image]

I would love it if that was a link to the removed question since I can view the deleted post so that I can easily locate and know which of my post was removed.

Comment: When viewing your user profile page, in your Questions tab you will see "deleted recent questions" link - clicking it would lead you to list of questions of yours that were recently (30 days, I think) deleted. :)

Answer (score 1):

> [image]

So it is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)?

Comment: You are special...

Comment: @Sha Thats actually strange: some have link and some don't...

Comment: maybe only those you deleted yourself?