# Keep downvoted removed post a link for non-10k users

Tags: feature-request, reputation, down-votes, deleted-answers

When an answer you downvoted is deleted, you get your reputation point back. This shows up in the user reputation tab:

> [image]

For 10k users, the title is a link to the answer. For others, it's just plain text.

It would be nice if it could still be a link, even though it would only go to the question. Instead, the solution is to go through reputation history looking for the original downvote, which does remain an active link:

> [image]

Maybe it's minor, but it can be useful to see what post was downvoted, when the title wasn't sufficient to remember.

---

**Related, but not a dupe:**

[Give me a link to my removed post in my reputation changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208725/give-me-a-link-to-my-removed-post-in-my-reputation-changes)

That request is for the post owner; this request is for all who downvoted

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bad idea. For anyone who does not understand the removal system, they will simply click the link thinking they'll be shown something relevant. They'll get to a question they may not even remember and become incredibly confused. If you can't be shown the content, it shouldn't be linked.

I would counter-propose that the hyperlinks should be *removed* on old events for now-deleted posts when you can't view them.

Comment: Maybe I just miss my 10k privileges here :)

Comment: To me, I still found the link useful, but I can understand how less experienced users would find it confusing

Comment: The question does still add context, and the "removed" is a clear sign that the link is to a removed post

Comment: @Monica The intention was to remove it when you can't see it. Basically make it the same as the removal event. Currently the original event is always linked no matter what.

Comment: I'm coming around to this idea. If the "downvoted" one were no longer a link, I wouldn't have even considered asking for the "removed" to be a link. Consistency is the key. Oh well, bring on the downvotes. I'd do it myself if I could at this point. ;)